# BBM-like iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, sms

I keep hearing all this hoopla about BBM (Blackberry Messenger) and I want in on the fun. Is there anything similar to BBM out there for the iPhone? I heard [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/) was something like it, but just wondering if there were any others.

Comment: Whats app, is cross platform, and will work on Windows, Android and BB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kik Messenger](http://kik.com) is relatively new and has the best feature from BBM (IMO);

Sent, Delivery, Read and typing status for messages

Unfortunately it was pulled from Blackberry's App World and actually blocked from pushing data on the Blackberry due to the fact that the founder was once an intern on the RIM BBM team.  RIM is actually in the process of [suing Kik](http://www.kik.com/blog/2010/12/a-sad-day-in-waterloo/) - which just goes to show you that they are onto something.

Even without proper support on Blackberry, it's highly recommended for iPhone, and there is an Android version as well.

Answer (score 4):

WhatsApp and [PingChat](http://appshopper.com/social-networking/pingchat-2) are the major games in town.  I've also heard a bit about [Cnectd](http://appshopper.com/social-networking/cnectd)

Nothing has really sold me yet, as I'm looking for proper delivery and read notification a la BBM.

Now if someone could figure out how to cross the impossible chasm to somehow connect into the BBM network, it would be a game changer.

Comment: Thanks! That's kinda what I thought (that there was nothing compatible with BBM). From what I've been reading, doesn't seem like anyone will be able to do so, but even if there was a universal app that all smartphones could use (even Blackberry users in place of/ in addition to BBM) would be cool.

Comment: I believe 2 or 3 of the ones I listed above ALSO have Blackberry versions - which is helpful if you can convince your BB friends to install and use it :)

Answer (score 4):

### [iMessage](https://support.apple.com/explore/messages) (Free)

iMessage, Apple's own messaging platform, can send and receive messages on iOS (5 or later on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch), macOS and watchOS, as long as they are connected to either a Wi-Fi or cellular network (3G). Starting with iOS 10, Messages includes support for third party apps.

Answer (score 1):

[LiveProfile](http://www.liveprofile.com/) recently launched and is clearly GUNNING for BBM.  Even closer in look, feek and functionality than Kik.

Even the fonts are similar:

[image]

They say their Blackberry App will be out soon, but I'd be surprised if RIM doesn't give them a hard time.  iPhone and Android versions are currently available.